# JavaScript: How to tell when a third party asynchronous content load has completed?

Tags: javascript, dom, asynchronous

I'm integrating job opportunities from a RecruiterBox account into a heavily stylised company website and I need to hook the click events to add additional functionality and animations. This I can do once the content has loaded.

The challenge I have is how to determine when the job list has finished loading because it's loaded asynchronously by third party scripts.

The JS snippet for loading job opportunities first appends the DOM with a couple of `<script>` tags to load in the third party JS. This then executes an asynchronous load of JSON data that is rendered into the DOM via Mustache templates.

I can detect when the DOM is being manipulated by adding a `'DOMSubtreeModified'` event listener to the parent element but what I can't detect is when the DOM manipulation has completed.

I also know the URL for the GET to obtain the JSON so my question becomes can I add some form of listener that will tell me when this GET operation has completed? Is this even possible?

---

**EDIT**

The call is an Ajax call but as its in a third party loaded script I have no control over it. Perhaps a better question would be can I hook into or add an event listener for the http responses for a given URL regardless of whether the script is mine or third party?

Here's an extract from the RecruiterBox script that's making the call if it helps:

```
var loadOpenings = function(oid, callbacks) {
            var url, source;
            url = API_HOST + (oid == 'all'  ? '/widget/clientid/openings/'.replace("clientid",CLIENT_ID)
                                            : '/widget/clientid/opening/openingid/'.replace("openingid",oid).replace("clientid",CLIENT_ID) );

            _rbox.xhr.request({
                url: url,
                method: 'GET'
            }, function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data.data);

                var i, len, ret;
                if(oid == 'all') {

                    for(i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
                        updateOpeningFields(data[i]);
                    }
                    ret = openings;
                }
                else {
                    updateOpeningFields(data);
                    ret = openings.get( oid );
                }
                callbacks.success && callbacks.success(ret);
            }, function(e) {
                callbacks.error && callbacks.error(e);
            });
        };
```

---

The following two gists list the full script loaded by the third party script loader. The function above is in rbox_api.js  NOTE: I've obfuscated id and company info in this script for security.

https://gist.github.com/jujudigital/d63efbad3032ec4ddd3d#file-rbox_impl-js
https://gist.github.com/jujudigital/2aa852a35eedd3c2ce3a#file-rbox_api-js

Comment: What are the 3rd party libs? Shouldn't it just be an ajax call that returns the json?

Comment: @PatsyIssa - I've edited the question to add a bit more context. Yes it is an AJAX call that returns the JSON but it's in the third party script. And that's my challenge - how do I get a notification in my code to let me know that the JSON has loaded.

Comment: Could you add your code that calls that function

Comment: @PatsyIssa there are two scripts added by the initial snippet 'widget' they are rbox_impl.js and rbox_api.js that function is in rbox_api.js. I've added a couple of gists to the end of the question.

Comment: @PatsyIssa the function above is called by the API fn this.getOpenings around line 285. going up the call stack a couple of steps via renderAppropriate (line 102 of rbox_impl.js) brings us to the $(document).ready function of the rbox_imp.js a around line 553- if that helps.